# Cannot Validate Certificate in AWS Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I have a Hosted Zone in Route 53 registered with name `subdomain.domain.com`. I'm now attempting to create a certificate in AWS certificate manager to protect second-level subdomains. I created a wildcard certificate `*.subdomain.domain.com` and then went to my domain DNS configurations and added the following records:

| Host Name | Type | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *.subdomain.domain.com | CNAME | _xxx.subdomain.domain.com | _xxx.xxx.acm-validations.aws. |
| subdomain.domain.com | NS | subdomain.domain.com | 4 nameservers from my hosted zone |

The certificate has been pending validation for hours. I have verified that the CNAME value is correct. The certificate validation method is set to DNS. Don't really know what else I'm missing.

#### UPDATE

I updated certificate definition to add a SAN for `*.domain.com` and then went to my DNS manager to add a CNAME record that got generated by AWS. The `*.domain.com` SAN got immediately validated, however, the second-level subdomain SAN is still pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone having similar issue, what fixed my problem is adding a CNAME record to the Hosted Zone. This can be done by going to your pending certificate in ACM and clicking on "Create records in Route 53." This allowed the validation to complete successfully after about 10 minutes.

Moreover, I believe the reason it worked for the APEX domain (ie domain.com) and not the second-level subdomain certificate is because of the NS record I added in my DNS configurations.

If you're creating a certificate using Cloudformation you can automate this by providing [DomainValidationOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-certificatemanager-certificate-domainvalidationoption.html) in your `AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate` resource and specifying the reference to your Hosted Zone. This will add the CNAME record automatically.